# jssor slider: vertical-align images – flexslider used instead

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider, jssor

I have a full-page jssor slider. As pictures are scaled to 'cover' they're cut off on the bottom if they're too tall.

I would like to be able to specify for each image whether it should vertically centered or bottom-aligned (or the default top-aligned), so I can make sure the important parts of each image are always showing.

I've tried `vertical-align` styles on the `div` containing the `img` with no luck.

Then I've tried calculating the required offset and applying a negative `margin-top` to images that are too tall – code below. This works at full width, but pushes the pictures too high when I resize the window below a certain width – leaving blank space on the bottom. I haven't been able to figure out how to stop this from happening.

Has anyone gotten something like this to work? Is there built-in functionality for this that I've missed?

HTML (I would add the show-bottom class only on relevant slides):

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 900px; display: none;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 900px; overflow: hidden;">
        {% for slide in slides %}
            <div><img class="slide-image show-bottom" u="image" src="/site_media/{{ slide }}" /></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var options = {
    $SlideDuration: 700,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuart,
    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $PauseOnHover: 0,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
    $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth) {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
        var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

        var scaleWidth = windowWidth;
        if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
            scaleWidth = Math.ceil(windowHeight / originalHeight * originalWidth);
        }


        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(scaleWidth);


        // I added this bit:
        // Adjust vertical alignment
        $( '.slide-image.show-bottom').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this)

            if ($this.height() > windowHeight) {
                $this.css('margin-top', windowHeight - $this.height())
            }
        })
        // End vertical alignment


    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems to have something to do with the `height: 900px;` set on the img. That is the height jQuery finds with .height(), regardless of the actual height that jssor has applied. How do I get the actual height after jssor has scaled it? That seems to be the crux.

Comment: Help us help you. JSFiddle it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I was able to do what I needed with Flexslider in the end.

```
<section id="featured" style="height:900px">
    <div class="flexslider" style="max-height: 100%;">
        <ul class="slides" style="max-height: 100%;">
            {% for slide in slides %}
                <li>
                    <img style="visibility: hidden" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ slide }}" alt="{{ slide.title }}" title="{{ slide.title }}">
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({options});

    scaleImages();

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        setSliderHeight()
        scaleImages()
    });

    function scaleImages() {
        var $images = $('.flexslider .slides img');
        $images.css("width", '');
        $images.css("height", $('#featured').height());
        setTimeout(function(){
            $images.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var parentWidth = $this.parent().width();
                var widthDelta = parentWidth - $this.width();
                if (widthDelta < 0 ) {
                    $this.css('margin-top', '');
                    $this.css('margin-left', widthDelta/2);
                } else {
                    $this.css('margin-left', '');
                    // scale width (to assimilate 'cover', take this out to 'contain')
                    if (widthDelta > 0) {
                        $this.height('auto')
                                .width(parentWidth);
                        var heightDelta = $('#home-featured').height() - $this.height();
                        $this.css('margin-top', heightDelta/2);
                        widthDelta = parentWidth - $this.width();
                        if (widthDelta < 0 ) {
                            $this.css('margin-left', widthDelta / 2)
                        }
                    }
                }
                $images.css('visibility', '');
            })}, 100);
    }

    function setSliderHeight(){
        $('#home-featured').height($(window).height());
    }

    setSliderHeight()
</script>
```

Note that rather than using 100vh, I set the height in js due to a bug in iOS with vh/vw properties on elements with dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to fill and align image in jssor slider.

1. Auto filling/alignment by specifying $FillMode option and specifying u="image" for image element. (e.g. <img u="image" ...)
2. Manual filling/alignment by removing u="image" from image element and specifying css for image element. (e.g. <img style="position: relative; top: ...px; left: ...px; width: ...px; height: ...px; ..." src=...)

To retrieve original size and scaled size of the slider, please use following api.

```
$ScaleWidth()  //formerly known as $GetScaleWidth()
//Retrieve scaled width the slider currently displays

$ScaleWidth(width)  //formerly known as $SetScaleWidth(width)
//Scale the slider to new width and keep aspect ratio

$ScaleHeight()  //formerly known as $GetScaleHeight()
//Retrieve scaled height the slider currently displays

$ScaleHeight(height)
//Scale the slider to new height and keep aspect ratio

$OriginalWidth()  //formerly known as $GetOriginalWidth()
//Retrieve original width of the slider

$OriginalHeight()  //formerly known as $GetOriginalHeight()
//Retrieve original height of the slider
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm afraid 1. won't work since it would return the height of the slider as opposed to the height of the individual images. Here's my JSFiddle after trying your suggestion under 2. http://jsfiddle.net/f4t4trwL/ – it's not displaying the pictures correctly.